# Max JSON column length in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

What's the max number of characters I can store in a JSON column in MySQL? I don't see this mentioned in the MySQL manual.

Comment: see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-json

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's a demo of what @JorgeLondoño is talking about.

Set the server's max allowed packet size:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*1024;
```

Exit and open the mysql client again, this time setting the client max packet size to match:

```
$ mysql --max-allowed-packet=$((1024*1024*1024))
```

Create a test table with a JSON column and fill it with the longest JSON document you can:

```
mysql> create table test.jtest ( j json );

mysql> insert into test.jtest 
  set j = concat('[', repeat('"word",', 100000000), '"word"]');
Query OK, 1 row affected (1 min 49.67 sec)

mysql> select length(j) from test.jtest;
+-----------+
| length(j) |
+-----------+
| 800000008 |
+-----------+
```

This shows that I was able to create a single JSON document with 100 million elements, and MySQL stores this in approximately 800MB.

I didn't try a longer document. I assume it maxes out at 1 GB, which is the largest value you can set for max_allowed_packet.

Comment: It is 1GB as you suggest: or `1073741824` in the config file.

Answer (score 24):

The size of JSON documents stored in JSON columns is limited to the value of the `max_allowed_packet` system variable. (While the server manipulates a JSON value internally in memory, it can be larger; the limit applies when the server stores it.)

```
Command-Line Format --max_allowed_packet=#
System Variable Name    max_allowed_packet
Variable Scope  Global, Session
Dynamic Variable    Yes
Permitted Values    Type    integer
Default 4194304
Min Value   1024
Max Value   1073741824
```

Answer (score 0):

Max allowed size for json data type field in MySql is **1GB**. If json is less than 8k in size then it will be store as part of the row itself, just like other data types.
On other hand json larger than 8k will be moved to seperate space as a document and individual SQL row will have pointer to that document.

I would recommend to handle error, if you think uploaded json can go beyond 1GB OR better if you can check the size of json before storing it into DB.

Information source link [here](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/how-large-can-json-documents-be/#:%7E:text=isolated%20and%20locked.-,Storage,the%20reset%20of%20the%20row.)