# mysql can we change maximum default JSON column length without changing maximum packet size?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711101/max-json-column-length-in-mysql) that max allowed json in 1 GB.

Can we somehow change this default behaviour to reduce this MAX limit to few MBs or any other value in particular table column with json datatype?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Max JSON column length in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711101/max-json-column-length-in-mysql), the maximum length of a JSON field is controlled by the `max_paquet_size` system variable.

As explained in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html, you can change this by adding

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=<xx>
```

in your `my.ini` or `~/.my.cnf` file. Don't forget to restart the service !

Comment: I want this to be reduced only for JSON datatype, not for all

Comment: @maverick Derlin already explained what's possible. What do you *really want to do though*? If you want to *restrict* the size of Json documents in a single table, restricting the maximum size of the type is *not* a good solution. If the database doesn't allow you to specify a maximum *field* size, you'll have to find a different way to do this, eg with a trigger