# Mysql json column constrain error (by json depth)

Tags: mysql, json, constraints, depth

If I set the data type to JSON in mysql and save the following content in it, the saving will be fine.

```
{
"root": [{
    "parent_01": [{
        "parent_02": [{
            "parent_03": [{
                "parent_04": [{
                    "parent_05": [{
                        "parent_06": [{
                            "parent_07": [{
                                "parent_08": [{
                                    "parent_09": [{
                                        "parent_10": [{
                                            "parent_11": [{
                                                "parent_12": [{
                                                    "parent_13": [{
                                                        "parent_14": []
                                                    }]
                                                }]
                                            }]
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

However, if I try to save one level more, I will receive an error message CONSTRAINT `projectpages.origin_html_structure` failed for `tailwindui`.`projectpages`.

```
{
"root": [{
    "parent_01": [{
        "parent_02": [{
            "parent_03": [{
                "parent_04": [{
                    "parent_05": [{
                        "parent_06": [{
                            "parent_07": [{
                                "parent_08": [{
                                    "parent_09": [{
                                        "parent_10": [{
                                            "parent_11": [{
                                                "parent_12": [{
                                                    "parent_13": [{
                                                        "parent_14": [{
                                                            "parent_15": []
                                                        }]
                                                    }]
                                                }]
                                            }]
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

If I use a string in the last dive, the save is fine and JSON_DEPTH returns 32 at the given column:

```
"parent_14": [{
    "parent_15": "String content"
}]

// returns 32
select JSON_DEPTH(origin_html_structure) from projectpages
```

However, if I change the string to an array, I will receive the above error message again and the save will fail:

```
"parent_14": [{
    "parent_15": []
}]
```

Why is this happening? The only thing that comes to my mind is that mysql has a depth limit set for the json column, but I haven't found this information anywhere on the internet. In any case, I need to store structures with deeper immersion. If I use the actual LONG TEXT or MEDIUM TEXT instead of the data type, I will save it correctly, but in that case it is not a native JSON. Please advice and any information. Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711165/6087422 I hope to helped for you

Comment: Increasing the value of max_allowed_packet does not help. Its value in my project is 1073741824 (1GB). There must be another limit I don't know about.

Comment: "If I use the actual LONG TEXT or MEDIUM TEXT instead of the data type, I will save it correctly, but in that case it is not a native JSON. " The JSON data type in MySQL is a simple alias name of LONGTEXT data type

Comment: Yes and no. As I wrote - if I set the data type LONG TEXT for the column, the saving will be fine. However, if I set the data type to JSON (well, alias), I get an error message. And I'm sure that the error is related to the amount of immersions, because (as I wrote again), if the value of the nested parent is "parent_15", for example, a string with a length of one million characters, the save will be fine, but if in this immersion I try to save even an empty field, I get an error. At the same time, if I save an empty field one dive higher (inside parent_14), again everything is fine.

Comment: Today I tested in MySQL and MariaDB, in MySQL the 15levels json successfully inserted, but MariaDB returned the CONSTRAINT error. Do you used MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: I use MySQL database.
Due to the strange behavior of MySQL, I was forced to use a different solution, so at the moment I'm storing records in a different way (not requiring such immersion). So don't waste your time. However, I still have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

yes, u'r right. the depth limit is 32.
[image]

[image]

[image]